# How to correctly type an array of arrays, when the types depend on each other?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I'm making a list of tenants in a shopping mall. Tenants are either shops or restaurants. Shops and restaurants can both be classified in a few different categories:

```
type ShopTypes =
    | `Accessories`
    | `Books`
    | `Clothing`;

type RestaurantTypes =
    | `Dive Bar`
    | `Elevated`
    | `Family`;

type Tenant<TenantCategory extends `shop` | `restaurant` = `shop`> = {
    category: TenantCategory;
    categoryType: TenantCategory extends `shop` ? ShopTypes : RestaurantTypes;
    label: string;
};
```

To make things easier I want to write the tenants as an array of arrays, and use a function to convert each "row" into a `Tenant`:

```
function toTenantList(...items: Array<
    [`shop` | `restaurant`, ShopTypes | RestaurantTypes, string]
>): Array<Tenant> {
    return items.map(([category, categoryType, label]) => ({
        category,
        categoryType,
        label,
    }));
}

const tenants: Array<Tenant> = toTenantList(
    [`shop`, `Accessories`, `Alice's Accessories`],
    [`restaurant`, `Dive Bar`, `Dan's Dive`],
    [`shop`, `Books`, `Barry's Books`],
    [`restaurant`, `Elevated`, `Exquisite Epicure`],
);
```

This throws an error:

```
Type '{ category: "shop" | "restaurant"; categoryType: ShopTypes | RestaurantTypes; label: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Tenant<"shop">[]'.
  Type '{ category: "shop" | "restaurant"; categoryType: ShopTypes | RestaurantTypes; label: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Tenant<"shop">'.
    Types of property 'category' are incompatible.
      Type '"shop" | "restaurant"' is not assignable to type '"shop"'.
        Type '"restaurant"' is not assignable to type '"shop"'.
```

In other words, Typescript is worried I might put a `RestaurantType` in a `shop` row, and vice-versa.

How do I set the constraint that if a row is a `shop` it should have a `ShopType` and if a row is a `restaurant` it should have a `RestaurantType`?

Comment: I think the problem is that "toTenantList" function is expecting return type of Tenant of only shops 

(as the return type is <Tenant> with default param to shop only)
However, we are passing array of arrays of Tenants that might be of ShopTypes or RestaurantTypes

I think this could be resolved by modifying the function's return type to Array<Tenant<"shop" | "restaurant">> 
OR 
use Type predicate and return only one type either shop or restaurant

Answer (score 1):

Your type Tenant is defined like this:

```js
type Tenant<TenantCategory extends `shop` | `restaurant` = `shop`>;
```

and used like this:

```js
function toTenantList(...items: Array<
    [`shop` | `restaurant`, ShopTypes | RestaurantTypes, string]
>): Array<Tenant>
```

`Tenant` is a generic type, but when you use it there are no generic arguments provided, therefore the default of `'shop'` is used.

If you want it to accept both types, you could instead use a `Tenant<'shop' | 'restaurant'>[]`.